# jQuery vertical navigation nenu with main links sliding to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Has somebody seen a vertical navigation menu where the box with the main links slides to the left, revealing the sub links beneath it? So the main box is above the submenu box.

I think it is not that hard in jQuery but I am no professional javascript programmer. An example would be great, if one exists.

Example picture: On the left the main menu

[image: menu]

Comment: If you are not a professional JS programmer I suppose you can draw us (and upload here) at least a Photoshop (or Paint or [Sumopaint](http://www.cumopaint.com) ) graphic, so we can play around or even suggest you an existent one, out there... :)

Comment: If the main links slides to the LEFT... I suppose the menu has to be positioned on the page to the right/middle ?! Right?

Comment: @ roXon  added a picture. And the menu should positioned be on the left also. I don't like it, but it has to be like that...

Comment: Ok, nice example, I'll try to figure out something. But just a question... The right 'bar' is actually a sub-menu, right? If so, it has not slided 'left' as you said in your Question, but it slides to the right. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, the right thing is the submenu, but it didn't slide to the right. The main menu was above that and slided to the left ;)

Comment: OK, working on it ... with the hover fn of course :)

Comment: I reedited the first demo and fixed some issues when fast moving the mouse over LI elements / animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/fwPZk/)

**Reedited demo** (fixed little issues) now is a bit more user frendly.

### [DEMO 2 reedited](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/8XNZ4/)

[image: submenuSlider]

You can find the comments in the first demo.
Good luck & happy coding!

Comment: Great! I was also trying to fix this but it didn't work like i thought. ;)

Comment: Now it's better? Might be also to 'empty' the submenu when other LI  eement is hovered. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple slightly different examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/W6Yu5/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/W6Yu5/4/

One of the great things about jQuery is how easy it is to learn. You could probably have created this after only studying jQuery for a few hours (assuming your HTML/CSS is already solid).

Comment: Really nice! I just need to change the click function to hover and it should be good. Maybe I will have a little problem with hovering out of the main box and not be able to choose a sub link.. I will see ;)

Comment: If you simply change .click to .mouseenter, this won't be an issue. And if you want the main menu to slide back into it's original position if you move your cursor off of it or the submenu, that just requires a little trick. You wrap all the menus in an extra div, and bind the mouseout event to that parent div. Here's an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/W6Yu5/5/